# Apache2 + Symfony4 + subfolder = issue

Tags: apache, symfony

i would like to know how can i have access to my symfony apps like that 
`ipofmyserver/symfony1` and `ipofmyserver/symfony2` with apache2

I've tried that but it doesn't work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony1

    Alias "/symfony1" "/var/www/html/symfony1/public"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/symfony1/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/symfony1/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ symfony1/index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/symfony1/public/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/symfony1_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/symfony1_access.log combined

    # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
    SetEnv APP_ENV prod
    #SetEnv APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>
    SetEnv DATABASE_URL "mysql://root:@localhost/symfony
</VirtualHost>
```

that config works but when i go on `/` i have the same thing and when i try to go on `symfony2` it doesn't work (same config as symfony1)

if someone can help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have two projects who are base in `/var/www/html/symfony1` and `/var/www/html/symfony2`

Comment: i don't understand very well can you explain me again because for me i make a symfony app for every project

Comment: Symfony1 and symfony2 do not interact together, they are two different applications

Comment: I want to make two different vhosts but first I want to start with one and then adapt it to a second vhost

Comment: there's no point trying with one if you're makjing into 2 just make 2?

Comment: of course, but why make two if one does not work?

Comment: because two will work..

Comment: so i will try it but does my configuration is good or not ?